# Check Datatype value at compile time

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, custom-controls, web-controls

I created a custom webserver control and given one property CustomWidth .This property is similar to width property of server controls.

Suppose if user set its  value at aspx page then I want to check its value at compile time.

If it is not on format of (int + "PX") px may be optional then build should be failed.

but i cann't use Unit datatype (which is used in server controls) for  this property.

Please suggest me solutions how can i check its value at compile time I want to create my own datatype for this property and check its value at compile time..

Thanks in advance  .

Comment: Which control does your Server Control inherit from? For example, TextBox, WebControl, Control.